# MongoDB: how to calculate distance within two coordinates without index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geolocation

I need to get the distance between two coordinates in an aggregate framework, but only the first match, in which I use $text, of the pipeline can use an index and I can't use $geoNear or $text in the same match query.
I solved the issue of returning the coordinates within a radius using:

```
{$geoWithin: {$centerSphere: [[lon, lat], (distance*1000)/6731]}}
```

But I cannot figure out how to calculate the distance without using an index.

These are the first two stages of the pipeline

```
[
{ '$match': { '$text': { $search: "some text" } } },
{ '$match': { coordinate: {$geoWithin: {$centerSphere: [[lon, lat],  (distance*1000)/6731]}}, type: 0 } }
]
```

It's possible, by adding a $project to this pipeline, to return the distance between [x,y] and [lon,lat]?

Comment: **IF** ( and that is a big "if" ) the aggregation framework actually supported the necessary math operators then it would be theoretically possible to do this with math, but it presently does it so it isn't possible right now. What you should consider here is *"do I really need that distance for further filtering?"*. If not then just work it out with math in the client from the returned results, which is a pretty simple process. If on the other hand you do need it, then it might be time to reconsider the `$text` search and use `$geoNear` as the first stage instead. Which would project distance

Comment: So the big question here is *"What is $text actually doing here?". Notably you are not "sorting" on the meta score, so the same result might just be possibly with a `$regex` search "after" a `$geoNear` operation. Typically `$text` is used for "ranking" results, just like a `$near` or `$geoNear` is meant to do, so the two in combination generally don't make much sense. I think your problem is likely solvable by that approach, but your question needs more detail on what really needs to be achieved in terms of the text match.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I use $text to sort my results, here i didn't write all my pipeline because i thought it was not necessary. I checked if mongoDB support math operator (something like $sin or $cos) but he doesn't, if i don't find a better solution i think i'll go with the math calculation in the client